# PHP: Encrypt/Decrypt Short String

Tags: php

I need to encrypt and decrypt short strings (Ex. 'product1234'). I have used mcrypt_encrypt and mcrypt_decrypt with various ciphers. The problem is that invariably it throws in extended characters into resulting string, which causes some issues with certain aspects of my application code that I cannot control.

So, the question is whether there is either a cipher that reduces the list of characters that are used in the encrypted string (i.e. leaving out things such as '+', '\', or '/').

Comment: Please show us the code which exhibits the problem, as it is hard to envision. It is very likely you can correct the issue via `base64_encode()`

Comment: @Michael base64_encode will always output a longer string than the original

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Cryptographic security? Just shortening the number of characters?

Comment: @Mahn I understood the request to be limiting the character set, not necessarily the length.

Comment: If you want to achieve a short string, but only using certain characters, you could gzip encode the string, then encode it in an arbitrary base (depending on what characters you want to use).

Comment: @Michael my bad, you are completely right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make `base64_encode` web safe:

```
function base64url_encode($plainText)
{
    return strtr(base64_encode($plainText), '+/=', '-_,');
}

function base64url_decode($b64Text)
{
    return base64_decode(strtr($b64Text, '-_,' '+/='));
}
```

Or use hexadecimal encoding:

```
bin2hex($plainText);

hex2bin($hexText);
```

Comment: Thanks. just one comma is forgotten:  return base64_decode(strtr($b64Text, '-_,', '+/='));